# Reload TableView data with more content after scrolling to end of tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am facing difficulty in how can i reload data in table view such as, am getting response from service upto count 10. now i need to get extra data if the count greater than 10 and reload that data into table view. to get that more data, i have service to implement. 
Can any one help in this.
Hope Understand my problem,and sorry if any mistakes are there.
Thanks for Help.

Comment: is there any mistake in my question or doubt.

Comment: why previous comments/answers were deleted.

Comment: Your service should have parameters "start" and "count" so that you can fetch results starting from the next record. In count parameter you can specify how many record to fetch in current call.

Comment: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:                                 But I am not sure, will it reload or add new rows.

Comment: To insert new rows you need to use insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: if you want to just reload new data in to existing rows, use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here how your 'Load More' in `UITableView` works

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/stableviewcontroller

Answer (score 4):

In the following delegate where you are setting your rows add one extra row

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return yourMutableArray.count+1;
}
```

The following delegate tells you that currently which cell is being created.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Under this you can add a check condition like

```
if(indexPath.row > yourMutableArray.count)
{

  // This means you are at the end of your table
  // Call your webservice here and append the next set of data into the yourMutableArray
  // You can also show an activity indicator over the extra cell here, Indicating the loading of new data
   [self performSelector:@selector(getDataFromWebservice) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
else
{
  // Do your cell settings here
}
```

and somewhere in your code where you are checking for the success of your webserivce add the following line to reload the table

```
[yourTable reloadData];
```

Make sure, that you append the new data into your MutableArray, else table will show only the latest data from the webservice.
Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When count is greater than 10 in cellForRowAtIndexPath, then nil service Array, re-init it and add new values of  data come from service call and then reload your tableView. I think this will help you. If you are still in problem. Tell me

Comment: In this case old values stored in the model will be lost. Like 1 to 10 will be lost and 11-20 will be visible.

Comment: ok, if so you can merge new array and previous array to new array.

Comment: Thats upto him, how he want to do, if his data contains millions of record then merging will be a costly affair.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your answers and they helped me for other context too.
i came out of this problem by adding footer view for a tableview, on footer view i added button and finally in the button action i called the service for more data, then data will be reloaded with new data with the help of, [tableView reloadData] method.
Hope this may help for some one else regarding this context.